# Scrape data from someone else's Google Sheets page using node.js?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, google-sheets

Can someone give me an idea of how one might go about scraping data from a Google Sheets page that is not owned by me?  Using API not an option.

I see a lot of tutorials about how to USE Sheets for storing web scraping data, but nothing about how to GET info FROM a Sheets page

Hoping I can do this using node.js. Anyone know the best way to go about this?

Comment: About `how one might go about scraping data from a Google Sheets page that is not owned by me`, can I ask you about the current situation? Because if the Spreadsheet is not publicly shared, your goal cannot be achieved.

Comment: It's publicly shared.  Am I over thinking this?  Maybe I should just approach it like any other web page.

Comment: To use the API, it has to have credentials created through Google Cloud console, correct?  I do not think the owners are willing to do this for me. Please correct me if I am misunderstanding this.   I will look into Apps Script, thank you.

Comment: Sorry. I should have had one more confirmation. From your replying, I could understand that the Spreadsheet you want to retrieve is publicly shared. In this case, the Spreadsheet is publicly shared which is not as the web publish? Or the Spreadsheet is publicly shared as the web publish? These are also important point for retrieving the values.

Comment: So can you confirm the following endpoints? 1. `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{spreadsheetId}/edit?usp=sharing` 2. `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{spreadsheetId}/pubhtml` Could you please tell me which endpoint you can access? Or both? From this result, I would like to propose the sample script.

Comment: trying /edit?usp=sharing yielded /edit#gid=0, and /pubhtml yielded page stating: "We're sorry. This document is not published."

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed 2 patterns for achieving your goal as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If those were not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values from the publicly shared Google Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using Node.js.
- From `trying /edit?usp=sharing yielded /edit#gid=0, and /pubhtml yielded page stating: "We're sorry. This document is not published."`, it was found that the Google Spreadsheet is publicly shared which is not as the web publish.

## Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the method of "spreadsheets.values.get" in Sheets API is used with the API key. Before you run the script, please retrieve your API key. [Ref](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys?hl=en)

### Sample script:

```
const request = require("request");

const apiKey = "###";  // Please set your API key.
const spreadsheetId = "###";  // Please set the Spreadsheet Id.
request.get(
  {
    url:
      `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${spreadsheetId}/values/A%3AZ?key=${apiKey}`,
    json: true,
  },
  (err, res, body) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(body);
      return;
    }
    console.log(body.values);
  }
);
```

- When above script is run, the values in the cells `A:Z` of the 1st tab are returned from the publicly shared Spreadsheet as 2 dimensional array.
- When you want to retrieve other tabs, please retrieve the sheet names using the method of spreadsheets.get in Sheets API. The endpoint of it is as follows.

  ```
    https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}?fields=sheets.properties.title&key={apiKey}
  ```

## Pattern 2:

In this pattern, Web Apps created by Google Apps Script is used.

### Usage:

Please do the following flow.

#### 1. Create new project of Google Apps Script.

Sample script of Web Apps is a Google Apps Script. So please create a project of Google Apps Script.

If you want to directly create it, please access to https://script.new/. In this case, if you are not logged in Google, the log in screen is opened. So please log in to Google. By this, the script editor of Google Apps Script is opened.

#### 2. Prepare script.

Please copy and paste the following script (Google Apps Script) to the script editor. This script is for the Web Apps.

```
function doGet(e) {
  const spreadsheetId = e.parameter.spreadsheetId;
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  const values = ss.getSheets().map(s => ({sheetName: s.getSheetName(), values: s.getDataRange().getValues()}));
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(values));
}
```

#### 3. Deploy Web Apps.

1. On the script editor, Open a dialog box by "Publish" -> "Deploy as web app".
2. Select **"Me"** for **"Execute the app as:"**.
3. Select **"Anyone, even anonymous"** for **"Who has access to the app:"**.
4. Click "Deploy" button as new "Project version".
5. Automatically open a dialog box of "Authorization required".

   1. Click "Review Permissions".
   2. Select own account.
   3. Click "Advanced" at "This app isn't verified".
   4. Click "Go to ### project name ###(unsafe)"
   5. Click "Allow" button.
6. Click "OK".
7. Copy the URL of Web Apps. It's like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec`.

   - **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please redeploy as new version. By this, the modified script is reflected to Web Apps. Please be careful this.**

#### 4. Testing Web Apps using Node.js.

Please access to the URL of your Web Apps using your browser by including the query parameters as follows. When you have already been logged in Google, the script of Web Apps is run.

```
const request = require("request");

const spreadsheetId = "###";  // Please set the Spreadsheet Id.
const url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec";  // Please set the URL of Web Apps.
request.get(
  {
    url: `${url}?spreadsheetId=${spreadsheetId}`,
    json: true,
  },
  (err, res, body) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(body);
      return;
    }
    console.log(body);
  }
);
```

- When above script is run, the following result is returned.

  ```
    [
        sheetName: 'Sheet1',
        values: [ [Array], [Array], [Array],,, ]
      },
      {
        sheetName: 'Sheet2',
        values: [ [Array], [Array], [Array],,, ]
      },
      ,
      ,
      ,
    ]
  ```

### Note:

- **When you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- The Google Apps Script is a simple sample script for explaining the method for achieving your goal. So please modify it for your actual situation.

## References:

- [Using API keys](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys?hl=en)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)
- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)
- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: This is so well written and comprehensive!  I'm sorry to say I've shelved this project for now and am deep into another one, so I'm not going to be able to try it right away, but I look forward to getting into it in a few weeks.  Thank you!

Comment: @AveryFreeman Thank you for replying. If my proposal was not useful for your situation, I apologize.